# How to post scanned QR Code value to Database on a server

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap

Am trying out barcode scanning/reader in phonegap. I have managed to read the QR codes but now am stack on how I can upload the scanned result to a mysql database. I have already installed the plugin for scanning and this part is working ok

Js for Scanning

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function scan()
        {
                   cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
                  function (result) {
                      alert("We got a barcode\n" +
                            "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
                            "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
                            "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled); 
                    // post to : "http://xxxxxxx.com/saveValue.php"     ------ Trouble on how to post to the server using this file
                  }, 
                  function (error) {
                      alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
                  });
        }
        </script>
```

Body content

```
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <a href="" data-role="button" onclick="scan()" >Scan</a>
        </div>
```

When QRC is scanned results pop up but I want once this pop comes, I then post the value to my mySQL database on my server. The following php works okay.

saveValue.php

```
        <?php
            if (isset($_POST['qrc'])) {
            $qrc = $_POST['qrc'];
            }

        include("con.php");


            $stmt =  $con->prepare("insert into qrc (qrc) values (:qrc)");

            $stmt->bindValue(':qrc', $qrc);

            $stmt->execute();


        ?>
```

Is there a way of adding a url like "http://xxxxxxx.com/saveValue.php" on the function Result on the JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Let me sum up:

1. You have a hyprid App running on a mobile phone
2. The user scans a QR code
3. The newly discovered QR code should be saved on a remote server running a MySQL database?

You accomplished step 1 and 2 already, right?

What I would do for step 3. I assume you want to build a solution with PHP.

1. Database & Table: Setup your database with an appropriate table for storing the information your need. Like User, scanned QR code. This is running on a remote server. Not your app.
2. API: Building a Rest API with PHP which is running on a remote server and has a consumable endpoint for the App. The API contains the logic to receive the data from your app (e.g.: User, QR code, etc.) and save them to the database table. Check out tutorials for that part.
3. App: Within your app you need a handling after the successful scan of the  QR code that initiate the API call. Because the data within your app has to be transferred to the server. In this API call you transfer the discovered QR code and additional data. The recipient of that call is the API you created the step before with PHP. Most likely this part is done by using JavaScript. Why? If you are building a hybrid app with Cordova your are building a single page web application with client-side technologies. Most Cordova hybrid apps are based on HTML, JavaScript and CSS. There are a lot of JavaScript solutions out there to perform an API call.

These solution would allow you to perform the storage of the QR code directly after you received the value from the Barcodescanner plugin. No need for submitting a form. If you want to show a form. Fine. Call the API within your submit handling.

Its a description on a very abstract level because its not a very specific question. Hope it helps anyhow.

Plus, thats only the technical aspect. Not talking about privacy and data protection.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your body content into a  element where you set

`<form action="http://xxxxxx.com/saveValue.php" method="post">`

Then add a `<button type="submit" value="Submit">` to do the uploading of the QR code.

This would be the simplest way I can think of to upload the data to the MySQL database.

Comment: Its not a mere PHP file. The PHP part is working already. The trouble is just like elaborated. I need JavaScript to do this for me.

Comment: Why would you need Javascript for it? All you can do with JS is to format the data the way you want to send to the server. Since JS is unable to talk to servers (unless you're doing it with Node or have an API available) then you'll need PHP to actually post the data.